# Evaluating serial replies with if statement

Tags: c, modem, atmel

I am trying to read network statuses from a modem using an atmel MCU, and then debug/restart based on certain status replies. I do so with the following code (and this works):

```
scanf("%s", state);
printf_P(PSTR("%s\n%d\n"),state,tempstate);

    if (*state=='4'|| *state=='7' || *state == '9' || *state == '11' || *state == '12' || *state == '13' ||*state == '19' || *state == '30' || *state == '31')
    {
        count++;
        if(count == 5)
            {
                send_string("ATZ\r");
                _delay_ms(10000);
                count = 0;
            }
        else{}
    }
```

However, when trying to do something similar in a pin change interrupt (used for a door switch) I can read the modem reply 'OK', but when trying to confirm that reply with an if statement, the reply is not recognized. See below.

```
    send_string("AT\r\n");
    scanf("%s", reply);
    printf_P(PSTR("\n%s"),reply);

    if (*reply == 'OK')
    {
    printf_P(PSTR("\nWill text contact now."));
    send_string("AT*SMSM2M=\"15555555TESTING\"\r");
    scanf("%s", reply);
    }
```

I cannot manage to get my code to enter that if statement after the 'OK' is received. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This `'OK'` is probably not what you think it is. `'` is for single chars(possibly multibyte).

Comment: What are the strict warnings you get for this code?

Comment: Pleae make a [mcve].

Comment: `*reply == "OK"` this does also not what you think it does. For comparing strings use the appropriate string compare function, otherwise you compare pointers which are guaranteed to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

For comparing the string `"OK"` (note the different quotes than in your code)
with what a `char* reply` points to, use

```
strcmp(reply, "OK")
```

Note that this returns 0 for identity.
Hence, an `if` similar to what you seem to try would be

```
if(!strcmp(reply, "OK"))
```

As mentioned by dbush in comment:
Note that you need to do this for the number comparisons as well, since you have strings containing numbers and not actual numbers.
Some of them (those comparing to a single character) misleadingly work, because you accidentally compare the first character of your reply string with a single-character char literal.

*(As usual for "string" read "null-terminated sequence of `char`s.)*

Comment: @masebee Note that you need to do this for the number comparisons as well since you have strings containing numbers and not actual numbers.

Comment: @dbush Good point. Thought it obvious but will add it to the answer, if you do not mind.

Comment: @Yunnosch Go ahead.